# HttpSession CDI injection in servlet project

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, cdi, httpsession

I have problem with my project for studies. I have simple project with one servlet and I need to have some CDI beans with diferent scopes. This part was realy simple, but I have to be able to inject HttpSession into each of me CDI beans. To resolve this problem I made ServletRequestListener to get HttpServletRequest object, I store this object in application scoped bean in ThreadLocal object and in this bean I have producer method for HttpSession object from stored HttpServletRequest. After that I'm able to inject HttpSession in any CDI bean except session scoped beans. Session is properly injected to that bean after session initialization, but for second request in the same session I have null pointer exception, because session bean is created(or deserialized) before RequestInitialized method and my producer return null value, which is illegal accoprding to stacktrace.

Here is the stacktrace from second request in one session:

```
    org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalProductException: WELD-000052 Cannot return null from a non-dependent producer method:  [method] @Produces @RequestScoped public pl.lab2.cdi.producers.SessionObjectsProducer.getSession()
    org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.checkReturnValue(AbstractProducerBean.java:217)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:300)
    org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:107)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:104)
    org.jboss.weld.proxies.HttpSession$776413422$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getId(HttpSession$776413422$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    pl.lab2.bean.SessionBean.toString(SessionBean.java:31)
    java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    org.jboss.weld.context.SerializableContextualInstanceImpl.toString(SerializableContextualInstanceImpl.java:60)
    java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.AttributeBeanStore.attach(AttributeBeanStore.java:109)
    org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractBoundContext.activate(AbstractBoundContext.java:66)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestInitialized(WeldListener.java:141)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And sources:

Listener

```
package pl.lab2.servlet;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import pl.lab2.cdi.BeanManagerHelper;
import pl.lab2.servlet.events.literal.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class ServletListener implements ServletRequestListener {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServletListener.class);

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        log.info("request destroyed event");
        BeanManagerHelper.getBeanManagerByJNDI().fireEvent((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest(), DestroyedLiteral.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        log.info("request initialized event");
        BeanManagerHelper.getBeanManagerByJNDI().fireEvent((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest(), InitializedLiteral.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

Holder

```
package pl.lab2.servlet;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import pl.lab2.servlet.events.Destroyed;
import pl.lab2.servlet.events.Initialized;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@ApplicationScoped
public class ServletObjectHolder {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServletObjectHolder.class);
    private final ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest> threadRequest = new ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest>();

    public HttpSession getSession() {
        log.info("get session");
        if (threadRequest.get() != null) {
            return threadRequest.get().getSession();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void servletRequestInitialized(@Observes @Initialized final HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("receive request initialization");
        threadRequest.set(request);
    }

    public void servletRequestDestroyed(@Observes @Destroyed final HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("receive request destroyed");
        threadRequest.set(null);
    }
}
```

Producer

```
package pl.lab2.cdi.producers;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import pl.lab2.servlet.ServletObjectHolder;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SessionObjectsProducer implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SessionObjectsProducer.class);

    @Inject
    private ServletObjectHolder servletObjectHolder;

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public HttpSession getSession() {
        log.info("get session");
        return servletObjectHolder.getSession();
    }
}
```

Session bean

```
package pl.lab2.bean;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.Serializable;

@SessionScoped
@Named
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    @Inject
    private HttpSession session;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SessionBean{" +
                "name='" + name + "', " +
                "sessionId='" + session.getId() + "'" +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And servlet:

```
package pl.lab2.servlet;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jboss.weld.context.ConversationContext;
import org.jboss.weld.context.http.Http;
import pl.lab2.bean.ApplicationBean;
import pl.lab2.bean.ConversationBean;
import pl.lab2.bean.RequestBean;
import pl.lab2.bean.SessionBean;
import pl.lab2.cdi.producers.SessionObjectsProducer;

import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ServletDispatcher extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServletDispatcher.class);
    @Inject
    private ApplicationBean applicationBean;
    @Inject
    private SessionBean sessionBean;
    @Inject
    private ConversationBean conversationBean;
    @Inject
    private RequestBean requestBean;
    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;
    @Inject
    @Http
    private ConversationContext conversationContext;
    @Inject
    private SessionObjectsProducer sessionObjectsProducer;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        conversationContext.setParameterName("cId");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        this.request(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        this.request(request, response);
    }

    private void request(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        log.info("request started in session " + request.getSession().getId());
        String cid = request.getParameter(conversationContext.getParameterName());
        if (cid != null) {
            conversationContext.activate(cid);
        } else {
            conversationContext.activate();
        }

        takeActions(request);
        updateData(request);
        printState(response.getWriter(), request);
    }

    private void printState(PrintWriter writer, HttpServletRequest request) {
        writer.print("<div>");
        writer.print("<div>Beans:</div>");
        writer.print(applicationBean.toString() + "<br />");
        writer.print(sessionBean.toString() + "<br />");
        writer.print(conversationBean.toString() + "<br />");
        writer.print(requestBean.toString() + "<br />");
        writer.print("</div>");
        writer.print("<div>");
        writer.print("<div>Data:</div>");
        writer.print("session id: " + request.getSession().getId() + "<br />");
        writer.print("conversation id: " + conversation.getId() + "<br />");
        writer.print("</div>");
    }

    private void takeActions(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if ("begin".equals(request.getParameter("conversationState"))) conversation.begin();
        else if ("end".equals(request.getParameter("conversationState"))) conversation.end();
    }

    private void updateData(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getParameter("application") != null) {
            applicationBean.setName(request.getParameter("application"));
        }
        if (request.getParameter("session") != null) {
            sessionBean.setName(request.getParameter("session"));
        }
        if (request.getParameter("conversation") != null) {
            conversationBean.setName(request.getParameter("conversation"));
        }
        if (request.getParameter("request") != null) {
            requestBean.setName(request.getParameter("request"));
        }
    }
}
```

To done it I use seam/servlet sources form github as example.

I've uploaded my current codes to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsasy2n07xhll2p/lab2.zip) just build, deploy on JBoss as 7.1.1.Final, go to localhost:8080/lab2, hit F5 twice and you will see the problem.

Comment: Seam servlet had some issues. Have you looked at the servlet module in [Apache DeltaSpike](https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/tree/master/deltaspike/modules/servlet)?

Comment: Thanks for answer:) I didn't find it before, but I can see alny a few differences and none of thme works:(
I tried before to get httpServletRequest from filter, with no effect
When I try to make my holder a static class ther is no diference
when I set HttpSession producer as SessionScoped I have such exception: rg.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalProductException: WELD-000053 Producers cannot declare passivating scope and return a non-serializable class:  [method] @ Produces @ SessionScoped public pl.lab2.cdi.producers.SessionObjectsProducer.getSession()

Comment: Hm, could be something in the weld servlet jar, because it isn't a fully integrated CDI impl.

Comment: But as far as I understand the weld servlet is embeded into jboss. I using maven in project and add dependency to weld-servlet with scope provided. I deploy my application on jboss 7.1.1.Final. If there is a bug in weld implementations, is there any way to fix it or any workaround?

Comment: I think the real problem is that weld tries to inject HttpSession into session bean before server calls filter or fire servletRequest event or call my servlet. I think that I should set request in my producer somehow earlier than I do this now. Is there such place?

Comment: You're using weld-servlet with JBoss AS 7.1.1? You only need to use weld-servlet if you're only using a servlet container like tomcat or jetty. A full application server (or at least one that is certified Web Profile such as as TomEE or any of the others) doesn't need this because it has CDI already integrated.

Comment: That's a possibility, but seems a bit unlikely. Also going through the code again, it seems like you've added a few extra layers of abstraction and complexity that don't need to be there.

I don't see a reason why you can't have a producer straight from your listener. Save the session in a ThreadLocal then have a producer that returns the session for that thread. The `ServletObjectHolder` is a bit overkill in this example.

Comment: Well, I just copy / pasted your code in a project and everything is working just fine under GlassFish 3. The only thing I had to add is the `@WebListener` annotation to the servlet request listener. Do you declare it in `web.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple the following will do what you want and work like a charm:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

// NOTE: this produces a request scoped session object because that's what the OP seems to want
@WebListener
public class SessionProducer implements ServletRequestListener {

    private static ThreadLocal<HttpSession> SESSIONS = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        SESSIONS.remove();
    }

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        SESSIONS.set(HttpServletRequest.class.cast(sre.getServletRequest()).getSession());
    }

    @Produces @RequestScoped
    protected HttpSession getSession() {
        return SESSIONS.get();
    }

}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I add logger to find out the order of method calls in yours class. For the first request(initialize of httpSession) the order was:
SessionProducer.requestInitialized
SessionProducer.getSession
SessionProducer.requestDestroyed
And it was fine, but for second request the first method called was SessionProducer.getSession and it was before SessionProducer.requestInitialized and because of that getSession returns null and jboss gives me exception WELD-000052 Cannot return null from a non-dependent producer method.

Comment: @gandalfml It works on GlassFish 3. Which JBoss version are you using, maybe I can reproduce it.

Comment: I deploy on JBoss as 7.1.1.Final

Comment: My solution, and solution from @rdcrng were enough to pass this part of project. My teacher doesn't know why this isn't working with session scoped bean and gave me all available point for this part. So the question is still open, because it just doesn't work and it will be nice to know why, but thank you for help:)

Comment: I've uploaded my current codes to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsasy2n07xhll2p/lab2.zip) just build, deploy on JBoss as 7.1.1.Final, go to localhost:8080/lab2, hit F5 twice and you will see the problem.

Comment: Sorry I took so long, was very busy. So, your project works as expected on GlassFish 3.1.2.2 (Weld 1.1.8 Final) and TomEE 1.5.2 (OWB 1.1.8), but fails on Jboss AS 7.1.1 Final (Weld 1.1.6). So it seems to be a problem with Weld 1.1.6, but a quick search of the issues did not bring up anything of substance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the problem was in my toString method in session scoped bean. In this method I tried to get session id, but for some reasons(logging I think) cdi calls toString method before request initialization. When I removed access to session object from toString method, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSF, indeed you will have acces to your httpsession with FacesContext...

we have not all your configuration and here i don't see the purpose of this configuration no one use servlet like that and you can acess to the http session via the request parameter not with injection...